# Service Intent. Android keep crash

Tags: android, android-intent

I am learning service intent. However it keep crashing. What happen? Anything wrong here?

```
public class SerIntent extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "remindme.appsrox.com.intentservice";

public SerIntent() {
    super("SerIntent");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
 Log.i(TAG,"HAHA");
}
}
```

I have declared at AndroidManifest.xml as well

```
<service android:name=".SerIntent" ></service>
```

This is what happen in main activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,SerIntent.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startService(<Intent>)` instead of `startActivity(<Intent>)` for starting `Service` or `IntentService`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SerIntent.class);
startService(i);
```

because `startActivity` is used for starting Activity.

Comment: @NganWeiPin: Always check logs in logcat. when app is crashing where you will easily find possible cause of issue yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use startService() method:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("com.sample.service.serviceClass");  
      this.startService(intent);
```